# Unable to connect - Apache2 in Ubuntu 12.04 VirtualHost

Tags: 12.04, apache2, mysql, lamp

I have followed the tutorial from here

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts

to set a local website.

I just changed the port `80` to `8081` because I have also `OpenStack` installed in my system.

I am unable to access my website via browser and getting error Mozilla browser just shows

`Unable to Connect`

Here is my `sites-available` file contents

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName cloud
DocumentRoot /var/www/cloud/public_html
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable listen on port 8081 for apache.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

add

```
Listen 8081
```

Restart apache

Comment: I did. 
Now it downloads the index.php file instead of displaying

Comment: try with this link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1653630 and this https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html